# "Sketching font" alternative to Comic Sans?

Tags: fonts, wireframe, mockups

In sketching (or mockup) tools such as [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/) and [WireframeSketcher](http://wireframesketcher.com/features.html) Comic Sans is used to give that "sketchy", hand drawn look. My only problem is, I'm *so tired* of that font.

Any suggestions for alternatives?

Edit: WireframeSketcher does not default to the Comic Sans font, but it's the one used to show an example of a "sketchy" look.

Comment: Not ... programming ... related.  Unless you're asking how to render an existing font in a handwritten way...

Comment: Surely, the use of wireframe tools must be programming related?

Comment: +1 for Comic Sans hate. Also, wireframing and mockups are programming related IMO

Comment: The reference is tenuous at best though - he could just as easily said "In web comics such as xkcd Comic Sans is used [etc etc]". He's asking for font suggestions, nothing more.

Comment: Then again, any reference to xkcd gets upvoted by default, so maybe he would have had a better response with that. =P

Comment: Just to be precise. WireframeSketcher does not default to Comic Sans font. But it's true that I show examples that do use it.

Comment: I think this is programming related. If design and the presentation of designs to non-technical stakeholders does not count as programming related then what else should be rejected? There's an open question about alternatives to Visio. Should that be rejected because I can use Visio to draw the floor-plan of my living room?

Comment: I mostly use Purisa: http://www.miriamruiz.es/debfonts/fnt-1754ebd3bc2e1eaf5b833389bd7b72de.html

Comment: Boo. The "Close Police" strike again. It *IS* most definitely programming related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google for "technical font".  I like [this one](http://eknp.com/php/fd.php?f=technical).

Answer (score 3):

Check out Casual, Bradley Hand ITC TT, Handwriting-Dakota, Marker Felt and Mistral, they all come loaded on Mac OS X 10.5.

Kyle

Comment: Its an official medical condition...

Answer (score 1):

If your printing is decent, you can have a font of your own made at www.yourfonts.com

Answer (score 1):

SitePoint recently had [an article](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/05/11/friends-dont-let-friends-use-comic-sans/) with some good alternatives to Comic Sans.  Good, in the case that you want to actually make comics.  They probably won't do so well as just placeholder text.

Here's a couple of examples

- [image: ZeroGene]
  <sub>(source: [sitepoint.com](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/comicfonts_clip_image017.jpg))</sub>
- [image: Turkey Sandwich]

There are download links within the [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/05/11/friends-dont-let-friends-use-comic-sans/).

Comment: Thanks for the reference... Although I was really looking for "sketching", not "comic" fonts.